# Spring rest support - Http code 422

Tags: spring, rest

Does anyone know if there is support for returning http code 422 from Spring MVC? I am developing some strictly RESTFul services using Spring MVC and I want to do data validations for all POST requests. 
The general convention that everyone is going towards is passing the validation messages back in the body but with a 422 response.
Is there some Spring bean that I can configure which automatically returns a 422 after it executes my custom validation code?

Thanks,
Gotz

Comment: is your question about how to set 422 in the response, or how to do such a functionality for all controllers at once?

Comment: Well, I want to write my own validator which extends some spring bean. I then want to override a method which calls my validator and allow this method to return a generic response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with an [`org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

It has 3 methods, `preHandle` is called before the request handler method is invoked, and `postHandle` after the request handler method retunrs and before the view is rendered, and `afterComplete` is invoked after the view is rendert.

I think you can use this to hook into the web request chain to modify request and response.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. Does it return a 422 automatically? Or do i have to explicitly set a 422? See, I don't want to do the latter thing because it then would mean i am forcing a strictly rest behavior into a framework that does not completely support REST

Comment: The `HandlerInterceptor` is just the hook, your have to implement its logic by your own.